# JavaScript literal, pointer value for key

Tags: javascript, arrays, literals

I have the following code:

```
name= "a";
value="b"
$.post("ajax.php", {name:value})....
```

However `ajax.php` will receive `name=b` instead of `a=b`.

How would I make it receive the latter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var obj = {};
obj[name] = value;
$.post("ajax.php", obj)...
```

Comment: And the *reason* it works is this: JavaScript object properties can be accessed in two ways: Using dotted syntax and a literal (`obj.prop = 42;`) and using bracketed syntax with a string (`obj["prop"] = 42;`), and of course in the latter case the string can be the result of any expression, including a simple variable reference (`name = "prop"; obj[name] = 42;`).

Answer (score 3):

To get the effect you desire you can do the following...

```
name = "a";
value = "b";
var values = {};
values[name] = value;
$.post("ajax.php", values);
```

Answer (score 2):

The name here is **not** treated as to be **replaceable** ...

you should **manually** write :

```
{a:"b"}
```

Comment: Im getting the key from the field being edited, fullname, username.. etc this is part of the function it would call

Answer (score 2):

```
name= "a";
value="b";

var o = {};
o[name]= value;

$.post("ajax.php", o);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a variable for key element *(if you consider using literal declaration)*. It has to be static

You need to do this:

```
$.post("ajax.php", {"a":value})
```

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to build the object programmably though.  You can create an object in this way:

```
var obj = {};
obj["a"] = "b";
```

So try this:

```
var obj = {};
obj[name] = value;
```

And pass that to the post call...